# How can set the tinymce's styles toolbar item's name to a custom localizable text?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I used the tinymce 4 before, with the styleselect toolbar item.
In that version 4 i can localize the styleselect dropdown button text.
After the version 4 to 6, i replaced the styleselect to styles toolbar item in the toolbar.
And i wanted to change the styles dropdown button text to a custom localizable text, but i could not find any workaround or answer.
So can i change the styles dropdown's text in the toolbar to a custom localizable text?
Now the text every time changing when i'm clicking to a new node, that is not selected before. I do not want this feature.

[image: styles toolbar item]

I hope somebody knows how can i solve this problem.

Thank you for your help, and have a nice coding day.